# JPanel doesn't add button and text field

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I don't understand why the `panel.add(txtnum1)` and `panel.add(button2)` doesn't show up when I compile the program. The `panel.add(button)` works just fine, my compiler doesn't throw any warning or errors, did I miss something?

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    panel.add(button);

    JTextField txtnum1 = new JTextField();
    txtnum1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
    panel.add(txtnum1);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Clear");
    panel.add(button2);
 }

}
```

Comment: The other components are probably added to the panel out of view. You should control how the components are displayed by using layout managers instead of setting absolute positions and sizes.

Comment: `JTextField txtnum1 = new JTextField();
    txtnum1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 50));` The size of a text field should be set using `setColumns(int)` for width in characters, and `setFont(bigOrSmallFont)` to change the height (and width).

Comment: *"my compiler doesn't throw any warning or errors, did I miss something?"* Compilers don't pick up many things that might go wrong at run-time. Abandon the concept that if it compiles OK, the code has no bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing GUI applications with Swing, I like to have this approach in the code that builds the `JFrame` (we assume a simple GUI that does not have `JPanel` containers inside `JPanel` containers and stuff like that):

1. Create `JFrame` and initialize it
2. Create `JPanel`
3. Create GUI components for that panel and add them
4. Add panel to the `JFrame` (repeat from **2)** for every `JPanel` inside the `JFrame`)
5. **Make the `JFrame` visible on the screen**

So, your code would look something like this:

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* step 1 */
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    /* step 2 */
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    /* step 3 */
    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    panel.add(button);

    JTextField txtnum1 = new JTextField();
    txtnum1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
    panel.add(txtnum1);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("Clear");
    panel.add(button2);

    /* step 4 */
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    /* step 5 */
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }

}
```

Tested and it works in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

**You should call setVisible(true) at the end, after all components have been added.**

Put `frame.setVisible(true);` at the end and it will work as expected.